# Paypal sandbox subscription button - testing buyer with no Paypal account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Gidday

I'd like to testing a subscription button sale for when the buyer doesn't have a Paypal account.

I set my sandbox account up as a Business-Pro one, but when I click the "No PayPal account? Pay using your credit or debit card" link, the new page still tells the buyer they need to have a Paypal account.

Is there something else I need to set up?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

With subscriptions the buyer will need to have a PayPal account, unless you specifically have added on the service for Enhanced Recurring Payments.  You would need to have this enabled on the account in order to be able to accept subscriptions/recurring payments where the buyer does not need to have a PayPal account.  If you can provide the email address of the test sandbox buyer account, I can check to see if this is enabled and try to enable it on my end if it is not already enabled.

Comment: Sure thing - payments-facilitator@songbookdb.com - thanks Chad

Comment: It's not allowing me to update the account on my end.  You may have to create a new biz test account and I can try to enable it on the new account.

Comment: OK - I've made two new accounts. I haven't altered them after going through the initial set up, so they are Business, not business pro, but I think I need them to be Pro. They are : testbiz_US@songbookdb.com (US) and testbiz@songbookdb.com (Aussie). Thanks again Chad.

Comment: I have enabled pro on your account with the email address of testbiz_US@songbookdb.com

Comment: Thank you for that Chad. On delving deeper, I realised that I cannot use a Pro account since I have an Australian PP account. I could if I set up a US PP account, bank account, address, but then tax is payable to the IRS, not the Australian Tax Office. If you know of another way I can have Pro so as to no be limited to the standard API with Enhanced Recurring Payments, please let me know.

Comment: You could set up a Australian Payflow account.  This would allow you to process credit card payments and recurring billing payments.

Comment: Ahh - so that's if I have a merchant bank account set up right? I don't have a merchant account, but will look into this as the business develops. I've almost finished coding in the payments system using Standard API subscription buttons and IPNs, together with Enhanced Recurring Payments set up. Thanks Chad.